# Hangman game in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I am a beginner in xcode and objective-c , And I just follow all the steps in the lesson I have watched in youtube to create hangman game. but there is an error in switch case 
when I enter wrong letter the images should be updated but what happen is when I enter the second wrong letter it just go to the default case and start again. 
( but in the correct situation, the length of string (WrongLetter) should be incremented by 1 and then enter the case 2 and so on).

The word is: colorado ( For those who will run the program )

```
if (match==NO)
{
    self.WrongLetter = [self.WrongLetter stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:LetterToCheck withString: @""];

    self.WrongLetter = [self.WrongLetter stringByAppendingString:LetterToCheck];


     switch  (self.WrongLetter.length) {
         case 1:
         {self.HangMan.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"head"];
             break;}
         case 2:{
            self.HangMan.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"HB"];
             break;}
         case 3:{
            self.HangMan.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"HBA"];
             break;}
         case 4:{
            self.HangMan.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"HBAs"];
             break;}
         case 5:{
            self.HangMan.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"HBAL"];
             break;}
         case 6:{
            self.HangMan.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CompleteMan"];
             break;}

         default:{
            [self SetHangManWord:self.CorrectWord];
             break; }

    } }
```

This is my project:
http://www.2shared.com/file/BLHIQ6kQ/HM_online.html

And this is the lesson in the youtube: 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I63BSGsFnEw

I would appreciate any help :)

Comment: add a `NSLog` there and print `WrongLetter` to the console. You are learning, try to find the error by yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSString *WrongLetter;
```

To this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *WrongLetter;
```

The WrongLetter property gets released too soon. And on second iteration it's just null.

It's a bad practice to name your variables with first letter capitalized. Usually class names get first letter capital.